# pscp exclude a directory

Tags: windows, putty, pscp

pscp -r   ../mydir/  xxx@example.com:/var/www/html/xxx/

copies everything under mydir, is there a way to exclude one subdirectory under mydir?

Comment: Isn't pscp a Windows program?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the scp command itself.

However ... install cygwin, and then ...

```
find . \! -name to_exclude -print | cpio -o | ssh where-ever "cd dest;cpio -i -"
```